# Jquery .val() da error al leer salto de linea

Tags: jquery

Tengo que rellenar un textarea y estoy usando la función .val() de Jquery, cuando esta el texto en una linea no hay problema, pero al tener 2 lineas da error de sintaxis "Unexpected EOF" en la linea 349 de jquery.

¿que podría ser?

los datos los cojo de mysql y están en formato utf8_general_ci

el codigo es este:

```
$('#art_detalles').val('<?=$DMoarticulos["detalles"]; ?>');
```

y el codigo html este:

```
<tr>
   <td class="derecha_listados"><label>Detalles:</label></td>
   <td class="izquierda_listados"><textarea id="art_detalles" name="art_detalles"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

si pongo un console.log con la variable de php da este error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'y' tambien en la linea 349 de jquery
Y es el primer carácter después del salto de linea.

con var_dump recibo este mensaje:

```
string(14) "ola y k ase"
```

¿hay alguna forma de forzar que lea el contenido de la variable como si fuera html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo hacia falta poner `preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'\n',$DMoarticulos["detalles"]);`
y todo solucionado.

Answer (score 2):

A veces hay caracteres no visibles, conocidos también como [`Byte Order Mark`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes) o simplemente **(BOM)**, el cual tiene en el sistema Unicode caracteres que no son imprimibles por definición.

El misterioso invisible carácter:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Analizamos el string: `"olay k ase"`:

```
$bom = "olay k ase";

$detect_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($bom);
echo $detect_encoding.PHP_EOL; 
// Resultado => UTF-8

$convert_encoding = mb_convert_encoding($bom, "ASCII", $detect_encoding);
echo $convert_encoding.PHP_EOL; // => 
// Resultado => ola?y k ase
```

[Resultado 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/87da71c2c29f7acc53be612e09cab458da573f64)

El resultado es que tiene la codificación `UTF-8` y el carácter `?` y la representación **BOM** en `Hexadecimal` sería `EF BB BF`

---

Ahora, esta es la única solución (y funcionando) que he [encontrado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20692384/2097224) para eliminar en `PHP` las representaciones **BOM**:

```
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

[Resultado 2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6de2078384796ea398f50fdb1d13fbb62ebdf02)

---

Comprobamos con tu código a ver si funciona, con y sin **BOM**:

con **BOM**:

```js
$('#art_detalles').val("ola     y k ase");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="art_detalles" name="art_detalles"></textarea>
```

sin **BOM**

```js
$('#art_detalles').val("olay k ase");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="art_detalles" name="art_detalles"></textarea>
```

---

**¿De donde aparece el BOM?**

> Depende como tengas la configuración de tu editor, puede que te añada
>   por defecto el **BOM**, y por lo visto también si copias algún fichero que no fue creado por ti, o estás probando en un servidor diferente con otro sistema.

**¿Cómo solucionar?**

> Editar el fichero con un editor que te permita guardar en
>   formato UTF-8 sin BOM, si no puedes cambiarlo, cambia de editor. `Notepad++` por ejemplo te permite esta operación.

O la solución en `PHP` para eliminar las representaciones BOM.

Comment: y hay forma de escaparlo?

Comment: @Killpe - Te he mejorado la respuesta

Comment: Genial, ya funciona :) mil gracias. No te doy mas puntos por lo currado de la respuesta porque no me deja XD